# Unix: Find duplicate occurrences in column in csv file, omit one possible value

Tags: bash, csv, unix, awk, duplicates

I am hoping for a line or two of code for a bash script to find and print repeated items in a column in 2.5G csv file except for an item that I know is commonly repeated.

The data file has a header, but it is not duplicated, so I'm not worried about code that accounts for the header being present.

Here is an illustration of what the data look like:

```
header,cat,Everquest,mermaid
1f,2r,7g,8c
xc,7f,66,rp
Kf,87,gH,||
hy,7f,&&,--
rr,2r,89,))
v6,2r,^&,!c
92,@r,hd,m
2r,2r,2r,2r
7f,7f,7f,7f
9,10,11,12
7f,2r,7f,7f
76,@r,88,u|
```

I am seeking the output:

```
7f
@r
```

as both of these are duplicated in column two. As you can see, 2r is also duplicated, but it is commonly duplicated and I know it, so I just want to ignore it.

To be clear, I can't know the values of the duplicates other than the common one, which, in my real data files, is actually the word 'none'. It's '2r' above.

I read [here](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/222103-check-identify-duplicate-values-first-column-csv-file.html) that I can do something like

```
awk -F, ' ++A[$2] > 1 { print $2; exit 1 } ' input.file
```

However, I cannot figure out how to skip '2r' nor what ++A means.

I have read the awk manual, but I am afraid I find it a little confusing with respect to the question I am asking.

Additionally,

```
uniq -d
```

looks promising based on a few other questions and answers, but I am still unsure how to skip over the value that I want to ignore.

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: Yes, two or more is what I mean by duplicate+. I will edit above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*how to skip '2r'*:

```
$ awk -F, ' ++a[$2] == 2 && $2 != "2r" { print $2 } ' file
7f
@r
```

`++a[$2]` adds an element to a hash array and increases its value by 1, ie counts how many occurrences of each value in the second column exist.

Comment: This works great, and I truly appreciate your easy-to-understand explanation of ++a!

Comment: deleted my own comment here -

Answer (score 1):

1. Get only the second column using `cut -d, -f2`
2. `sort`
3. `uniq -d` to get repeated lines
4. `grep -Fv 2r` to exclude a value, or `grep -Fv -e foo -e bar …` to exclude multiple values

In other words something like this:

```
cut -d, -f2 input.csv | sort | uniq -d | grep -Fv 2r
```

Depending on the data it might be faster if you move `grep` earlier in the pipeline, but you should verify that with some benchmarking.

Comment: So something like infile=cut -d, -f2; infile=sort $infile; infile=uniq -d $infile; grep -v 2r $infile ? Please excuse my newness to this syntax.